# How can I assign the text imputed into an entry box (tkinter) to variable in python script and run the script by pressing a button?

Tags: python, tkinter, jupyter-notebook, tkinter-entry

I have a python script that takes the file path and runs the following script:

```
    file = 'C:/Users/crist/Downloads/Fraction_Event_Report_Wednesday_June_16_2021_20_27_38.pdf'
    
    lines = []
    with pdfplumber.open(file) as pdf:
        pages = pdf.pages
        for page in pdf.pages:
            text = page.extract_text()
            print(text)
```

I have created an entry box with tkinter:

```
     import tkinter as tk

master = tk.Tk()
tk.Label(master, 
         text="File_path").grid(row=0)

e = tk.Entry(master)


e.grid(row=0, column=1)


tk.Button(master, 
          text='Run Script', 
          command=master.quit).grid(row=3, 
                                    column=0, 
                                    sticky=tk.W, 
                                    pady=4)

tk.mainloop()
```

I would like to assign the File_path imputed in the entry box by the user to the "file" in the script and run the script when pressing the "Run Script" button. How can I do that?

Comment: Change it into a function and use `e.get()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to spawn a file dialog instead of using a `tkinter.Entry`:

```py
# GUI.py
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import tkinter as tk

# Create the window and hide it
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

# Now you are free to popup any dialog that you need
filetypes = (("PDF file", "*.pdf"), ("All files", "*.*"))
filepath = askopenfilename(filetypes=filetypes)

# Now use the filepath
lines = []
with pdfplumber.open(filepath) as pdf:
    ...

# Destroy the window
root.destroy()
```

Comment: Can you please help me understand the code? So after the choosing the pdf file from the popup, i should copy the file path and insert it in the entry box?

Comment: @Cristian Why not just use it in your other function (the one that uses it in `with pdfplumber.open(file) as pdf`)? That will bypass the need for the entry.

Comment: @Cristian Did I misunderstand the question? From what I understood, you want to get the user's chosen file inside your other script (the one that handles the `.pdf`).

Comment: oh that makes sense. although idk how to do that...So after selecting the file with the code you provided, how will i assign the path to "file" from the pdfplumber.open(file) function? @TheLizzard

Comment: I want the user to select their file and then use that file into my pfdplumber funtion and run the script for the selected pdf

Comment: Instead of the `print` store the result of `askopenfilename(filetypes=filetypes)` in a variable and call your other script with that variable. I will update my answer to show you what I mean.

Comment: I'm trying to install pdf_handling in anaconda and i'm not sure why i'm not able to do so

Comment: @Cristian No it's not a module like that. In python you can import your own files. See how I wrote `# pdf_handling.py` at the start of the second code snippet. It's in a new file named `pdf_handling.py`. The first script imports the seconds one. You can do that in python as long as both files are in the same directory.

Comment: You don't need to install anything.

Comment: I copied your code and i get this error: No module named 'pdf_handling'. Both files are in the same directory

Comment: @Cristian Is the second script named `pdf_handling`?

Comment: The second script is named: PDFtoTemplate.ipynb

Comment: i tried changing pdf_handling to PDFtoTemplate but no luck...

Comment: @Cristian That means that you are using IPython NoteBook. I updated my answer so it's only one file

Comment: i'm using jupyter notebook. I copied the new code you sent, and also renamed my second module as pdf_handling, but i seem to get the same error: No module named 'pdf_handling'

Comment: @Cristian Sorry my bad, I forgot to remove the `import pdf_handling`

Comment: should i also remove pdf_handling.handle_pdf(filepath)? Cause as is the code gets stuck and doesn't run

Comment: @Cristian Yes, by bad again. I updated my answer

Comment: yeah...not sure why but the code never runs...and i never get the popup either

Comment: Should i import these at the very beginning or inside the tk?
import pdfplumber, import pandas as pd,  import re

Comment: @Cristian The imports should be somewhere between the start and where you use `with pdfplumber.open(filepath) as pdf`. It should matter where. You should get a file select dialog and the file path should be sored inside the `filepath` variable.

Comment: i put the imports before lines = []...but it still doesn't work...

Comment: Thank you so so much! Really appreciate all your help